# Adobe DPS...Invoke the Library from within a folio

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-dps

Is there a way to automatically invoke the library from within a folio without having to tap the Library button?
We have are trying to update a folio without human intervention and have the code to automatically download the new version once you tap the Library button. The code also relaunches the folio.
I need a way to go from the folio to the library programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You should be able to do this using the `adobeDPS.configurationService.gotoState()` method (see [docs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/digitalpublishingsuite/LibraryAndStoreSDK-2.30/docs/symbols/adobeDPS-ConfigurationService.html#ConfigurationService#gotoState))

```
adobeDPS.configurationService.gotoState("Library")
```

The string you pass to `gotoState` must match the label of the tab. If the tab says "Library" (it's case sensitive), then the above code should work.